# Maximum tiling by Y Hexomino

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, puzzle, tiling, packing-problem

"Y Hexomino" has a shape as shown in the picture.

[image]

What is the maximum number of Y Hexomino that can be placed on a $13\times 13$ chessboard, where each Hexomino does not overlap?

From the diagram below, we can place a maximum of 24 Hexominoes.
However, how can we prove that no more can be placed?
In the general case, it seems that we can place a maximum of $6n^2$ hexominoes on a $(6n+1)\times (6n+1)$ chessboard , using a similar method to the $13\times 13$ case.
How can we demonstrate the validity of this  conjecture?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I've checked by computer that you can't place 25, but it does feel like there should be a direct proof.

Comment: I used integer linear programming to confirm that $24$ is the maximum. The linear programming relaxation yields an upper bound of $26+1/3$, which is tighter than the area upper bound of $28+1/6$.

Comment: Thank you both. However, I'm still looking forward to a mathematical proof, as computer programs cannot verify cases of chessboards with dimensions of (6n+1)x(6n+1).